# React - <a> tag keeping blue color despite CSS telling otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, I'm working with a bootstrap navbar and button within it.
However the link was blue, that was ugly. So I put this in my CSS

```
a:link {
  color: inherit;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

a:active {
  color: inherit;
}
```

At first I thought it worked, but it only worked partially.

If I'm off the button, the color is correct

[image: off the button]

if I'm on the button but off the text, it's also correct

[image: hover button but not text]

however if I hover over the text it goes to the default blue link color

[image: over text]

this is the button code

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
  type="submit"
  onClick={this.logout}
>
  <a href="/">Log Out</a>
</button>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why use inherit when you can just set it to white, and then a dark green or something when its been activated?

Comment: because there's other places I don't want it to be white

Comment: So create a class and use CSS how its intended to be used

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the first time I'm using both JS and CSS... I'll see to it, but do you think tha'll solve my issue?

Comment: Yeah of course, it's just the active or hover color. If you create a `.button-white-text' or similar class, you can control it for that one button. There's no need to try and control multiple instances of different things when a simple class and basic CSS will sort the issue you've got

Answer (score -1):

Change the `button` element to an `a` element.

```js
<a href="/" className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
  onClick={this.logout}
>
  Log Out
</a>
```

You wouldn't need the CSS rules if you do this.